# Why isn't my lighting working properly? Are my normals messed up?

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting, normals

I'm relatively new to OpenGL and I am trying to draw a 3D model (loaded from a 3ds file using lib3ds) using OpenGL with lighting, but about half of it is drawn in black.

[image: model]

I set up the light as such:

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

GLfloat ambientColor[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f};
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientColor);

glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
GLfloat lightColor0[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
GLfloat lightPos0[] = {4.0f, 0.0f, 8.0f, 0.0f};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos0);
```

The model is in a VBO and drawn using `glDrawArrays`. The normals are in a separate VBO, and the normals are calculated using `lib3ds_mesh_calculate_vertex_normals`:

```
std::vector<std::array<float, 3>> normals;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < model->nmeshes; ++i) {
  auto& mesh = *model->meshes[i];
  std::vector<float[3]> vertex_normals(mesh.nfaces * 3);
  lib3ds_mesh_calculate_vertex_normals(&mesh, vertex_normals.data());
  for (std::size_t j = 0; j < mesh.nfaces; ++j) {
    auto& face = mesh.faces[j];
    normals.push_back(make_array(vertex_normals[j]));
  }
}
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normal_vbo_);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             normals.size() * sizeof(decltype(normals)::value_type),
             normals.data(),
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

The problem isn't the vertices; the model is drawn correctly when drawing it as a wireframe. I also fixed the normals in Blender using <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. What could be the problem? Should I store the normals in a different order?

Comment: could the vertices/indices be in counter clockwise order instead of clockwise, or vice versa? also, could you post the 3ds file?

Comment: If you enable backface culling, will half of the triangles disappear?

Comment: Quite an odd combination, seeing C++11 with the OpenGL fixed function pipeline. :P

Answer (score 1):

Since pressing Control-N removed your problem, the normals your model had prior to you pressing Control-N were not correct. So yes, your normals *were* messed up, but your client code is most likely fine.